# reshape machine learning input data for different algorithms

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, training-data

I am experimenting in sklearn learn classification with some NLTK type tutorials. Can someone help me understand why the [sklearn MLP neural network](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier.html) can handle different input shapes but the other classifiers cannot?

My input `training` data is a `numpy.ndarray` with shape `(62, 2)`

This is the only thing I know how to do for train test split (any tips appreciated if there is something better)

```
train_x = list(training[:,0])
train_y = list(training[:,1])
```

The data looks like this if I `print(train_y)`:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
```

The MLP classifier seems to work just fine.

```
model = MLPClassifier(learning_rate_init=0.0001,max_iter=9000,shuffle=True).fit(train_x, train_y)
```

But if I try to use the other sklearn classifiers, like:

```
model = GaussianNB().fit(train_x, train_y)
```

I get the error:
`ValueError: y should be a 1d array, got an array of shape (62, 15) instead.`

I think I need to incorporate `.reshape(-1,1)` somewhere in my code but not sure where. Any tips appreciated not a lot of wisdom here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see the labels `y` are in the `one-hot` form. Basically label is a vector with size equal to the number of classes. Each element of that vector is zero except at the index which represents the exact class. That element is **one**. This is why the shape of y is `(62, 15)`

U need to transform the label `y` into a form in which your labels will be represented as integers.

Example:
In this example we have 6 classes: `ranging from 0 to 5`

`[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0] -> 3`

`[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] -> 0`

`[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] -> 1`

You can do this by using the `numpy.argmax(y, axis=1)` which will return the index of element which has maximum value along the specified axis. Take a look at the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)

Comment: Thanks for posting this answer makes a lot of sense now....